# Building a Predictive Parser

Tags: java, parsing

I´m building a predictive parser for some productions of Cocol/R

Here is the grammar I´m working with:

```
ScannerSpecification =
[ "CHARACTERS" { SetDecl } ]
[ "KEYWORDS" { KeywordDecl } ]
[ "TOKENS" { TokenDecl } ]
{ WhiteSpaceDecl }.
SetDecl = ident '=' Set '.'.
Set = BasicSet { ('+'|'-') BasicSet }.
BasicSet = string | ident | Char [ ".." Char ].
Char = char | "CHR" '(' number ')'.
```

the curly braces ({}) mean: 0 or more
the squared brackets ([]) mean: 1 or none

And this is the Input:

```
COMPILER Test

CHARACTERS
letter = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".
digit = "0123456789".
hexdigit = digit+"ABCDEF".
```

This is the code I´ve wrote until now:

```
    public void Cocol( ){
    if(in.hasNextLine()){
        currentLine = in.nextLine();
        numLines++;
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(currentLine, " ");
        if(tokenizer.hasMoreElements()){
            lookahead = tokenizer.nextToken();
            match("COMPILER",false);
            match("ident",false);
            ScannerSpecification();
            match("END",false);
            match("ident",false);
            match(".",false);

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("ERROR: Expected:"+"COMPILER"+"But Found: "+" ");
            System.out.println("Line :"+numLines);
        }

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("ERROR: Expected:"+"COMPILER"+"But Found: "+" ");
        System.out.println("Line :"+numLines);
    }

}

public void ScannerSpecification(){
    // 1 o mas veces “CHARACTERS” { SetDecl }
    if(lookahead.equals("CHARACTERS")){
        match("CHARACTERS",false);
        while(SetDecl(true)==true){
            SetDecl(false);

        }
    }
    if (lookahead.equals("KEYWORDS")){

    }

    //if( WhiteSpaceDecl()){

    //}
    match(".",false);


}

public boolean SetDecl(boolean backtrack){
    if (backtrack){
        if(match("ident",true)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    else{
        return match("ident",backtrack)&&match("=",backtrack)&&Set(backtrack)&&match(".",backtrack);
    }
    return false;

}

public boolean match(String terminal,boolean backtrack){

    AFN afn = new AFN(terminal);
    boolean result;
    if(terminal.equals("number")){
        result = automataNumber.simularAFN(lookahead, automataNumber.inicial, conjuntoSimbolos);

    }
    else if(terminal.equals("ident")){
        result = automataident.simularAFN(lookahead,automataident.inicial,conjuntoSimbolos);

    }
    else if(terminal.equals("string")){
       result =  automataString.simularAFN(lookahead,automataString.inicial,conjuntoSimbolos);

    }   
    else if(terminal.equals("char")){
        result = automataChar.simularAFN(lookahead,automataChar.inicial,conjuntoSimbolos);

    }
    else{
        if(this.lookahead.equals(terminal)){
            result= true;
        }
        else{

            result= false;
        }
    }
    //Verificando si se esta haciendo backtrack o es un match "real"
    if(backtrack==false&&result==true){
        if(tokenizer.hasMoreElements()){
            lookahead = tokenizer.nextToken();
        }
        else if(in.hasNextLine()){
            do{
                currentLine =in.nextLine();
                numLines++;
            } while (currentLine.equals(""));
            tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(currentLine, " ");
            lookahead = tokenizer.nextToken();
        }   
    }
    else if(backtrack==false&&result==false){
        System.out.println("ERROR: Expected:"+terminal+"But Found: "+lookahead);
        //Encontrando linea
        try {
            ArrayList<Integer> line = findLineOf(lookahead);
            System.out.println("Near Line: "+line);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ScannerCocol.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return result;
```

The problem I´m facing is when I´m on the SetDecl Production. Since I´m ignoring spaces and getting the input until a new Whitespace is found what I get on my token after parsing the ident 'letter' is:

"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".

With the '.' included. As expected, I get an error because I should just be reading until the last 
' " ' of the string. I don´t really know how to make the parser discern when it should stop reading when there´s no whitespace between terminals. I get similar problems if I remove the whitespace between the id´s and the '=' symbol.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks